# Has the ICC ever ordered to arrest any Western or pro-Western politician?

Tags: history, western-world, international-criminal-court

Referring to [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/78771/41763), it appears as if the ICC is biased in favor of the West, since all the people it has punished were enemies of the West. But since crimes which can be prosecuted by the ICC are also committed by Western countries, or at least by allies of the West, I am wondering if there has ever been an attempt by the ICC to arrest any Western or pro-Western politicians for their crimes.

Comment: I down-voted because referring solely to that linked question, it does not at all appear as if the ICC is biased in favour of anyone… merely that Nebenzya hopes the audience might be innocent enough to mistake unsupported vitriol for fact. Oddly enough, that Soviet stance pretty-much mirrors the responses the late Shah of Iran somehow managed to keep a straight face while giving to the press in the 1970s - only Nebenzya is more vituperative.

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin "it does not at all appear as if the ICC is biased in favour of anyone…" And why then they punishing only enemies of the West? Have you posibly any counterexamples, as this is exactly what the question asking for.

Comment: I've seen only one allegedly complete list of ICC warrants: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_indicted_in_the_International_Criminal_Court. Does that cover this?

Comment: You mean has it issued warrants against western politicians? The ICC doesn't travel around the world arresting people.

Comment: @Stuart F OK posibly what you called it is a more corect definition.

Comment: It’s likely any correlation has a different cause: anyone suspected of war crimes would likely by that fact alone make them an "enemy of the west". Also, many who are "enemies of the west" are also "enemies" (I.e., viewed similarly) of many non-western countries.

Comment: @Stuart F I made an edit, hope now it´s beter.

Answer (score 41):

In 2020, the International Criminal Court(ICC) started [an investigation into alleged warcrimes perpetuated by US soldiers in Afghanistan.](https://www.theguardian.com/law/2020/mar/05/senior-icc-judges-authorise-afghanistan-war-crimes-inquiry)
So far, these investigations have not led to any indictments of any specific US politicians or soldiers, but the last US president [seemed to consider it a serious threat](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/jun/11/trump-icc-us-war-crimes-investigation-sanctions).

The ICC [is also investigating alleged warcrimes perpetuated by Israel against Palestinians](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-56687437).

Comment: [U.S.: 'Hague Invasion Act' Becomes Law](https://www.hrw.org/news/2002/08/03/us-hague-invasion-act-becomes-law)

Comment: Both of the mentioned investigations here are just *preliminary* investigations. This is just looking into complaints to see if there's an actual case there, not the prosecution of an actual case. That doesn't mean they won't proceed, but at least in the US's case its been in this same phase for more than a decade, so that doesn't look likely.

Comment: Investigating but not actually finished and wrapped up and the suspects convicted, there clearly were war crimes in Afghanistan its just because of Money they kept on investigating... until everyone will forget about it.

Answer (score 31):

Arguably, they have.

The ICC in its 2 decade history has only handed down [about 53 indictments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_indicted_in_the_International_Criminal_Court), and they were all related to what looks to me like a bit over a dozen different conflicts or events. So its arguable how statistically-significant any tendencies one finds in the data are.

With that caveat, it looks like the most pro-Western politician they have put out a warrant for was [Mahmoud al-Werfalli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmoud_al-Werfalli), who was in charge of the Army of the Western-backed elected government of Libya during the post-Ghadaffi Civil War. This was mostly on the basis of that Army's execution of prisoners.

After that, we have the first 5 warrants the ICC ever issued, which were for figures involved in the Ugandan [Lord's Resistance Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_Resistance_Army). This is a [Dominionist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion_theology) group, with ties to evangelical Dominionist groups in the USA. They aren't *officially* in very good smell in most "western" nations. They are on the US Terrorist Watch List. However, most of their outside support and moral inspiration comes from that movement. Dominionists are [big backers of US Conservative politicians](https://news.northeastern.edu/2022/11/15/dominionism-republican-candidate/), and thus the Republican Party.

There are also some other Christian vs. Muslim conflicts, where you'd think "The West" would perhaps be more sympathetic to the Christians, but the ICC has indited figures on both sides. This has happened particularly in Congo, Kenya, and Central Africa, for a total 21, or about 40% of their indictments.

---

### Predictors

The "western" frame is a bad one because it really doesn't allow us to predict who *will* get indited. Lots of international bad actors that aren't beloved in Brussels, London, or Washington, are conspicuously absent from this list. So let's look at who *is* on the list. What do they have in common? I made [a quick (I wish!) spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rcVBiwmOGoe8usYy3_HjYrJVCnpz7JCagaBOv3vraWI/edit?usp=sharing) based on public data from Wikipedia, the ICC, and some other sources where need be.

One thing is that every one of them seems to be for a person holding or supporting an exclusive identity-based ideology (Some flavor of religious or ethnic nationalism), or it happened in the aftermath of a highly-contested election. So it looks like if you aren't a hard identity nationalist and don't cheat on your elections, you're probably safe from the ICC no matter where you live.

The second is that, prior to last year, a non-African had never been indicted. Sure, they made up for it with 5 Europeans since then, but still that's pretty dang glaring. A simplistic "East-West" framing simply does not fully explain this distribution.

The obvious first explanation is that perhaps Africa is where most of the relevant crimes are happening. Wikipedia lists [4 genocides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genocides) since the ICC was formed, and 2 of them happened in Africa. Of the 123 [wars and conflicts they list since 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars:_2003%E2%80%93present), 58 of them (47%) were in Africa. So its probably fair to say this accounts for a decent amount of the attention Africa is getting, but seemingly not all of it.

I'd thought to look at [Democracy Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index), on the theory that this could be a halfway decent proxy for places potential criminals may feel their victims are powerless enough for them to get away with their crimes, but frankly that map comes close to doubling as a conflict map<sup>1</sup> There are certainly *preliminary* investigations in these other places, but for whatever reason they never seem to advance to actual investigations.

[image]

Another possibility is that African nations are just in a uniquely unstable region where the general public trusts international institutions more than local ones for dispensing justice in political matters. The ICC by policy steps in only if there's a complaint, and if local proceedings are felt to be not up to the task.

One other explanation that comes to mind is flat out racism. Its tough to resist comparing the ICC's propensity for prosecuting Africans to the American criminal justice system, which [incarcerates African-Americans at quadruple the rate of its white citizens](https://www.prisonpolicy.org/blog/2022/05/19/updated_charts/).

---

<sup>1 - interesting thing to investigate, but beyond the scope of this question.</sup>

Comment: It is perhaps worth being impressed that Putin's behavior became so egregious that he actually managed to pierce whatever the barrier here is.

Comment: I don't quite understand the pivot from "pro-western or not" framing in the question to "african or not" in your answer.

Comment: @Hackworth - I started looking into the question asked, and this is where an objective look at the data took me. If the framing of the question ends up being a bad way to look at it, that's generally considered a reasonable thing to put in an answer. It certianly wouldn't have fit in a comment. If it makes you feel better, I suppose I could put a big "No." up at the top?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't let your own prejudices get the better of you here, especially considering your last statement? Surely Africans investigated by the ICC can be pro-western, anti-western, or neutral, so why would that be a bad framing?

Comment: @Hackworth - I'm actually looking into that, and have yet to find anyone that I could firmly call pro-western **or** anti-western. If there's a common thread (other than being African), its ethnic nationalisim and warfare. They generally don't appear to be the kind of folks who care much about international relations one way or another. Putin's kind of unique there.

Comment: ...which again just backs up the statement in this answer that pro/anti western feeling is just not a useful way to frame this.

Comment: Another explanation is that African countries aren't influential enough to hassle/threaten the court, unlike what happened when the ICC went after Israel and the US. And like Russia is also trying to replicate, by the way. They indicted the court officials,  https://www.politico.eu/article/putin-russia-icc-criminal-case-moscow-ukraine-war/ which exposes them even to extradition requests in countries like India (they won't extradite their own nationals to Russia, but would other countries' nationals, per Russia-India treaty.)

Comment: @Fizz - Indeed. However, a lot of the other places that got preliminary investigations but didn't (or haven't yet) made it past that early phase are places like Syria, Myanmar, Afghanistan, etc. Not exactly international political powerhouses.

Comment: Sure, racism probably plays a role. However, I think there is still a major difference relative to US incarceration patterns: many prisoners in the US are innocent or are guilty of quite minor crimes, and these people account for a substantial chunk of racial disparities in imprisonment, whereas my impression is that the people indicted by the ICC *are* guilty of quite major crimes—it's just that there are many *others* who are also guilty who are not indicted.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Again, that's quite similar. It isn't so much that great masses of that one ethnicity are "innocent" (although incorrect prosecutions are more likely to happen too), so much as it is that when they break a law, they are far more likely to get arrested, prosecuted, convicted, and get harsher sentences. At every stage, even ignoring the previous stages, the racial stats are out of whack.

Comment: It's up to you, but the last bit could be made a bit less controversial by simply noting that e.g. Burundi or Gambia has levelled that accusation at the court. The comparison with the US internal justice is probably not so relevant, since the US is not part of the court. Maybe something like the situation in France https://www.rfi.fr/en/france/20230216-survey-shows-nearly-all-black-people-in-france-have-experienced-racism or the UK https://www.ohchr.org/en/press-releases/2023/01/uk-discrimination-against-people-african-descent-structural-institutional ?

Comment: The catch however with these allegations (against the ICC) is that they generally popped up after it went after government suspects in those countries. They were rather happy when the ICC was investigating non-state actors there. https://youtu.be/2RaraCu8zXg?t=592

Answer (score 7):

The US literally threatens to arrest ICC judges who hold trial against Americans. Read some of these comments from John Bolton:

> "If the court comes after us, Israel or other US allies, we will not
> sit quietly," Bolton said.
>
> "We will ban its judges and prosecutors from entering the United
> States. We will sanction their funds in the US financial system, and
> we will prosecute them in the US criminal system," he said.
>
> "We will do the same for any company or state that assists an ICC
> investigation of Americans," he said.
>
> "The United States will use any means necessary to protect our
> citizens and those of our allies from unjust prosecution by this
> illegitimate court," Bolton said.
>
> "We will not cooperate with the ICC. We will provide no assistance to
> the ICC. We certainly will not join the ICC. We will let the ICC die
> on its own."

https://www.france24.com/en/20180910-usa-trump-threatens-arrest-icc-judges-american-soldiers-afghan-war-crimes

Comment: John Bolton is... not exactly a source of mainline centrist American political thought, much less mainline Western political thought.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Regular voters of both parties hate John Bolton but he is absolutely representative of the USA political leadership. He's held top offices within US government for decades. Those quotes were made as the US official National Security Advisor. The Biden Administration is staffed with Bolton's allies, even if regular Biden voters hate that idea and don't want to acknowledge that. Bolton promoted Biden in 2020 and has large influence on the Biden Administration.

Comment: Now American fell in love with ICC because it hate Putin now.